# How can I disable the label when plotting pandas data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I tried using `label=None` in the plot command, in which case `matplotlib` chose the key of the data as a label. I find this behavior unintuitive and expected to have full control over the label when I set it explicitly.
How can I disable the label of a plot involving data from a `pandas` dataframe?

Here is a small example, which shows the behavior:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]})
plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'], label=None)
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

This results in the following plot:

[image]

In case it matters, I'm currently using matplotlib version 1.5.1 and pandas version 0.18.0 in the following python installed from macports:
Python 2.7.11 (default, Mar  1 2016, 18:40:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin

Comment: You can pass an empty string: `plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'], label='')`

Comment: Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you pass an empty string then it results in this plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]})
plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'], label='')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just pass an empty label.  Matplotlib doesn't bother making a legend entry in that case.  The `label=None` argument is the default, which the plotting function detects, telling it to make up a label.

(Of course, in this case, you could just not use `plt.legend`...)